# daily image download

Tags: download, wget, fopen

I'm looking for a solution to automate downloading of charts from stockcharts.com.

If you click on the following URLs, stockcharts will automatically generate an image file (sc.png).  Note the only different is the stock ticker symbol at the end.

I would like to download these charts daily to folder on my computer.

http://stockcharts.com/h-sc/ui?p=D&b=5&g=0&id=p96079191618&a=173667279&s=ELR.TO
http://stockcharts.com/h-sc/ui?p=D&b=5&g=0&id=p96079191618&a=173667279&s=GOOG
http://stockcharts.com/h-sc/ui?p=D&b=5&g=0&id=p96079191618&a=173667279&s=AAPL
http://stockcharts.com/h-sc/ui?p=D&b=5&g=0&id=p96079191618&a=173667279&s=KFN

I'm guessing maybe using wget, curl or perl.

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here, unless you're looking for someone to provide a working solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the URLs don't change from day to day, a cron job plus wget/curl should work fine.

Comment: Agreed.  A cron job is perfect for this.

Comment: Sounds simple enough.  I'll give it a try.